# Template assignment operator overloading mystery

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

I have a simple struct `Wrapper`, distinguished by two templated assignment operator overloads:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {

  Wrapper() {}

  template <typename U>
  Wrapper &operator=(const Wrapper<U> &rhs) {
    cout << "1" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
  template <typename U>
  Wrapper &operator=(Wrapper<U> &rhs) {
    cout << "2" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

I then declare a and b:

```
Wrapper<float> a, b;
a = b;
```

assigning `b` to `a` will use the non-const templated assignment operator overload from above, and the number "2" is displayed.

What puzzles me is this: If I declare `c` and `d`,

```
Wrapper<float> c;
const Wrapper<float> d;
c = d;
```

and assign `d` to `c`, neither of the two assignment operator overloads is used, and no output is displayed; so the default copy assignment operator is invoked. Why does assigning `d` to `c` not use the const overloaded assignment operator provided? Or instead, why does assigning `b` to `a` *not* use the default copy assignment operator?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why does assigning `d` to `c` not use the const overloaded assignment operator provided?

The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator, which is declared as follows, is still generated:

```
Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper&);
```

An operator template does not suppress generation of the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator.  Since the argument (a const-qualified `Wrapper`) is an exact match for the parameter of this operator (`const Wrapper&`), it is selected during overload resolution.

The operator template is not selected and there is no ambiguity because--all other things being equal--a nontemplate is a better match during overload resolution than a template.

> Why does assigning `b` to `a` not use the default copy assignment operator?

The argument (a non-const-qualified `Wrapper`) is a better match for the operator template that takes a `Wrapper<U>&` than for the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator (which takes a `const Wrapper<U>&`.

Comment: +1 for *An operator template does not suppress generation of the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator*.

Answer (score 6):

From the C++03 standard, §12.8/9:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template** member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

And §12.8/10:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly.

The fact that your `operator=` is a template makes it **not** a copy assignment operator, so the class' implicit copy assignment operator is still generated by the compiler.

Comment: What is it then if not a copy assignment operator? So what are you supposed to do instead - just make a CopyFrom function template or something like that?

Comment: @DavidDoria : It's an assignment operator, just not a _copy_ assignment operator.