# Assignment-Operator for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

For clarification, I'm citing James McNellis answer in [the post "Template assignment operator overloading mystery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625790/template-assignment-operator-overloading-mystery/5625834#5625834):

> The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator, which is declared as follows, is still generated:

```
Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper&);
```

Now I have a similar class and would like to know what the definition of this operator needs to look like.

Here's the class for recall:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper;
```

What is now the correcting match:

```
template<typename T>
Wrapper& Wrapper<T>::operator=(const Wrapper&)
```

or

```
Wrapper& Wrapper::operator=(const Wrapper&)
```

?

Or is this just the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
template<typename T>
Wrapper& Wrapper<T>::operator=(const Wrapper&)
```

which is really just shorthand for

```
template<typename T>
Wrapper<T>& Wrapper<T>::operator=(const Wrapper<T>&)
```

The other version would apply to a non-template class named `Wrapper`, it has no effect on your templates.