# Template assignment operator with rvalue reference argument behaves differently with vs2013 and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, assignment-operator, rvalue-reference

Why does the following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    template<typename T>
    A &operator=(T &&rhs) {
        std::cout << "A::operator= called" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    a1 = A();
    return 0;
}
```

print `A::operator= called` using Visual Studio Express 2013 but prints nothing when compiled with gcc-4.9.1.

What would be the correct behavior?

Edit: [Template assignment operator overloading mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625790/template-assignment-operator-overloading-mystery) does not address VS/gcc compiler differences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template assignment operator overloading mystery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625790/template-assignment-operator-overloading-mystery)

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991874/why-is-this-code-trying-to-call-the-copy-constructor) in Visual Studio. It doesn't implicitly generate move-constructor and move-assignment-operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is correct. Your type has an implicitly declared move assignment operator, which is a better match than the template.

If you cause the implicit move assignment to be suppressed, e.g. by adding a user-declared destructor, then your template will be used.