# Assignment operator to reference template type requires non-const overload

Tags: c++, templates, reference, assignment-operator

I'm trying to wrap my head around a copy assignment operator issue. I am at a loss what is really going on, though I have some ideas (listed at the end). This is a problem since I am using a 3rd party library with no control on its classes.

Lets say you have a templated container with copy assignment operator. This operator accepts another container with a different template, and tries to static_cast the other type.

```
template <class U>
vec2<T>& operator=(const vec2<U>& v) {
    x = static_cast<T>(v.x);
    y = static_cast<T>(v.y);
    return *this;
}
```

This is fine for simple assignment, however when using references for T, you get a compile error about const value types. If you add another overload that accepts a non-const reference, it will compile and work.

I've made a simple example which should help illustrate the issue.

```
template <class T>
struct vec2 final {
    vec2(T x_, T y_)
            : x(x_)
            , y(y_) {
    }

    template <class U>
    vec2(const vec2<U>& v)
            : x(static_cast<T>(v.x))
            , y(static_cast<T>(v.y)) {
    }

    template <class U>
    vec2<T>& operator=(const vec2<U>& v) {
        if (this == &v)
            return *this;

        x = static_cast<T>(v.x);
        y = static_cast<T>(v.y);
        return *this;
    }

    // Fix :
    /*
    template <class U>
    vec2<T>& operator=(vec2<U>& v) {
        x = static_cast<T>(v.x);
        y = static_cast<T>(v.y);
        return *this;
    }
    */

    T x;
    T y;
};
```

And how I am trying to use it :

```
int main(int, char**) {
    vec2<int> v0 = { 0, 0 };
    vec2<int> v1 = { 1, 1 };
    vec2<int&> test[] = { { v0.x, v0.y }, { v1.x, v1.y } };

    vec2<int> muh_vec2 = { 2, 2 };
    test[0] = muh_vec2;
    printf("{ %d, %d }\n", test[0].x, test[0].y);

    return 0;
}
```

The latest AppleClang will generate the following error :

```
main4.cpp:18:7: error: binding value of type 'const int' to reference to type 'int'
      drops 'const' qualifier
                x = static_cast<T>(v.x);
                    ^              ~~~
main4.cpp:63:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'vec2<int
      &>::operator=<int>' requested here
        test[0] = muh_vec2;
                ^
```

What I understand from this, is that somehow the compiler is trying to assign by const value. But why and is there a non-intrusive solution to this issue?

I did find a similar question here : [Template assignment operator overloading mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625790/template-assignment-operator-overloading-mystery)

My conclusion after reading the issue is : maybe a default assignment operator is causing the issue? I still do not understand why though :/

Here is an online example : https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fc5CERb9voCTXHiN

Comment: `x = static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(v.x)` perhaps. Or maybe even simply `x = v.x;` and rely on implicit conversions.

Comment: So remove_reference works. Do you know why? Would you know of an alternative which doesn't require modifying the container?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to fix buggy code without modifying said code?

Comment: "This is a problem since I am using a 3rd party library with no control on its classes."

Comment: I suspect `vec2<T>` simply wasn't designed to be used with a reference type for `T`. So one way to fix the problem without modifying `vec` is simply to avoid using it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class U>
vec2<T>& operator=(const vec2<U>& v)
```

within this method, `v` is a name for a const view of the right hand side.  If `U` is `int`, then `v.x` is a `const int`.

If `T` is `int&`, then `this->x` is a `int&`.

```
this->x = static_cast<int&>(v.x);
```

this is obviously illegal: you cannot static cast a const int to a non const reference.

A general solution basically requires rebuilding the `std::tuple` or `std::pair` machinery.  SFINAE can be used to bootstrap it.  But in general, structs containing references and those containing values are usually quite different beasts; using one template for both is questionable.

```
template <class T>
struct vec2 final {
  template<class Self,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Self>, vec2>>{}, bool> =true
  >
  friend auto as_tuple( Self&& self ){
    return std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Self>(self).x, std::forward<Self>(self).y );
  }
```

then we can do SFINAE tests to determine if `as_tuple(LHS)=as_tuple(RHS)` is valid.

Doing this for construction is another pain, as LHS's tuple type needs massage before the constructibility test can work.

---

The more generic you make your code, the more work it takes.  Consider actual use cases before writing infinitely generic code.

Comment: OK, so if I understand this correctly. You'd use this helper internally to select what casting/function to call? I'm having difficulty seeing how to apply as_tuple to my problem.

Comment: @scx take `operator=(U&&)` and SFINAE test if `as_tuple(*this)=as_tuple(U&&)` is valid, and use that internally as your implementation.  To be clear, I am saying that gives you what you seem to want; I am not saying it is a good idea.

Comment: Oh ok. I am trying to rethink my container, but I don't really see another way (yet). I'll use the std::remove_reference for now instead, as it seems a little less involved. Thanks for the help!