# Overload assignment operator and rule of zero

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I have written a template class `A<T>` and I am making use of the rule of zero (I let the compiler generate the destructor, copy/move constructors and assignment operator overloadings).
However, I need now a customized assignment operator that takes a different type `B<T>` as argument:

```
A<T>& operator=(const B<T>& rhs);
```

Will this implementation prevent the compiler from generating the default destructor etc.?
My guess is no, because the compiler generates

```
A<T>& operator=(const A<T>& rhs);
```

which is just entirely different from the overloading I want to implement.

Comment: IMO assignment operator and rule 3/5/0 are almost orthogonal, [this table confirms that](https://i.imgur.com/NVdnpFa.png). Almost since there is move semantics: so if you have move assignment then you should have move constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! @MarekR One question regarding your table: I guess `A<T>& operator=(const B<T>& rhs);` technically is not a copy assignment, but just an assignment operator overloading, since copy assignment would need some object `A<T>` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment Does this table still hold regarding move constructor/assignment?

Comment: Even `template <typename U> A<T>& operator=(const A<U>& rhs);` is not a copy assignment. (When U==T, `A<T>& operator=(const A<T>&)` would be selected).

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, indeed. Also in this case, it's neither copy nor assignment operator.

Comment: See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625834/12002570): *"An operator template does not suppress generation of the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my understanding, adding a `operator=` overload will **not** prevent the compiler from generating the default one according to the rule of 0.

I base this understanding on the fact that your `operator=` overload is **not** in fact a [**copy assignment**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), **nor** a [**move assignment**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).
**Therefore the rules about generaing default constructors and assignment operators are not relevant**.

I verified it with MSVC.

You can use the code below to verify with your compiler:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    B(T const & n) : bn(n) {}
    T bn{ 0 };
};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    A(T const & n) : an(n) {}
    A<T>& operator=(const B<T>& rhs)
    {
        an = rhs.bn;
        return *this;
    }
    T an{ 0 };
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a1{ 5 };
    A<int> a2{ 6 };
    std::cout << a2.an << ",";
    a2 = a1;    // Use default assinment
    std::cout << a2.an << ",";
    B<int> b{ 3 };
    a2 = b;     // Use custom assignment
    std::cout << a2.an << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be: **6,5,3**:

**6** is the value `A<int> a2` is constructed with, **5** is the value assigned from `A<int> a1`, and **3** is the value assigned from `B<int> b`.

**Note:** an alternative would be to use a [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), as @LouisGo commented (see above).